# How does an S-box introduce confusion

Tags: symmetric, substitution-cipher

I'm trying to find the logic for introducing the S-box, but having trouble understanding why. In a simple cipher, e.g.

```
c = pt xor key
```

I understand that I can easially find the key when choosing the plaintext myself

```
key = pt xor C
```

But I don't see why an S-box can help in this at all, given that the S-box is public.

```
C = S[pt xor key]
```

Because then I could just do

```
key = S^-1[pt xor C]
```

I understand by adding multiple rounds and keys, this gets harder, but what is the S-box giving, when we can just reverse it?

Comment: Hint: think multiple rounds.

Answer (score 3):

As kodlu and kelalaka said, you don't know the in/out of the Sbox when there are multiple rounds.
Another need for the Sbox (or Sboxes) is to make a cipher non-linear. AES, for example, consists of affine transformation only apart from the SubBytes step (which is a reversible Sbox). If this step was omitted, the cipher would become affine, so it can be represnted as `C = Lx+v`, and is easily breakable with polynomial time and data by solving linear equations (By knowing `L` and `v` you can encrypt/decrypt any ciphertext).

Answer (score 2):

Even with two rounds and known plaintext you *don't know* the intermediate round inputs to the sbox since you don't know the round keys. This necessitates the brute forcing of the key bits, or other structural analysis. There's your confusion.